# How to fit a dynamic PHP form in a div (to be able to fit fullpage.js)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, fullpage.js

I am using ajax to generate a dynamic form inside some div, showing many inputs in a column. I would need that these inputs could be "spread" in many columns, so that the div could have a fixed height.

How would you approach this issue (in a simple way, so that a non-programmer like me could understand and try to implement)?

I am using fullpage.js, so I need the div containing the form not to exceed, 90% of the page, basicly.

Take this simple form as the example:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=somelimit; $i++) {
        echo '<input type="text" name="number'.$i.'" /> 
        <input type="text" name="other'.$i.'" /> 
        <input type="button" id="button'.$i.'"><br>
        ';
    }
```

The html/css is just a div which would have avaiable like 100% width and 90% heigh.

Comment: Your problem is CSS related. So please put here the output HTML and the CSS you used so far for this design.

Comment: The html/css is just a div which would have avaiable like 100% width and 90% heigh. I added that info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may want to look to flexbox for this, coupled with an `inline-block` fallback (`display: flex`, `display: inline-block`).

Note that layouts may vary for browsers which do not yet support flexbox.

Here is an example:

```css
.form-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.form-field {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
  <ul class="form-fields">
    <li class="form-field">
      <label for="input1">Input 1</label>
      <input type="text" id="input1">
    </li>
    <li class="form-field">
      <label for="input2">Input 2</label>
      <input type="text" id="input2">
    </li>
    <li class="form-field">
      <label for="input3">Input 3</label>
      <input type="text" id="input3">
    </li>
    <li class="form-field">
      <label for="input4">Input 4</label>
      <input type="text" id="input4">
    </li>
    <li class="form-field">
      <label for="input5">Input 5</label>
      <input type="text" id="input5">
    </li>
    <li class="form-field">
      <label for="input1">Input 6</label>
      <input type="text" id="input6">
    </li>
    <li class="form-field">
      <label for="input7">Input 7</label>
      <input type="text" id="input7">
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

You don't need fixed heights on any of the elements; `display: inline-block` will deal with this.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution! Unfortunately, it is not perfect for me, because I needed the inputs to be ordered by columns, like 1,2,3,4, and then it reaches the bottom and creates the other column, continuing 5,6,7.
Do you have any idea of solution for this?

Comment: You can use CSS columns for this: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/columns/